# Undefined variable: services (View: C:\Users\user\Documents\Laravel Projects\myapp\resources\views\pages\services.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I still got an error "undefined variable: services". can any one help me in this one? here's the code on my controller.

```
public function services()
{
    $data = [
        'title'    => 'services',
        'services' => [
            'Web Design',
            'E-commerce App',
            'Data Integration',
            'Database Management',
        ],
    ];

    return view('pages.services')->with('data', $data);
}
```

here's the code on my display page.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Hello, this is the services page.</h1>
    @if (count($services) > 0)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($services as $service)
                <li>{{ $serivce }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
@endsection
```

I hope some help me in this one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are not passing a variable named `services` to the view, you are passing an array which will be named `data` which in that array is a key named `services` ... you should just pass that `$data` array so it can use the keys as the variables for the view

Comment: @lagbox, there's no wrong in my controller at all hehe. I just figured out lately that i'm having a trouble in my view page which I misspelled the variable "service". 

extends('layouts.app')

section('content')
    <h1>Hello, this is the services page.</h1>
    if (count($services) > 0)
        <ul>
            foreach ($services as $service)
                <li>{{ $serivce }}</li> //as you can see here I misspelled it but now i changed it to service so things works fine now. 
            endforeach
        </ul>
    endif
endsection

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here.

Firstly, since you're using `->with('data', $data)`, this is going to make `$data` available in your blade file, rather than destructuring the values within `$data` e.g.

```
@if (count($data['services']) > 0)
```

and

```
@foreach ($data['services'] as $service)
```

---

Secondly, you have a typo inside you like:

```
<li>{{ $serivce }}</li>
```

should be

```
<li>{{ $service }}</li>
```

---

If you would like to remove the need for using `$data`, you can simple pass the array as the second argument to the `view` function:

```
public function services()
{
    return view('pages.services', [
        'title'    => 'services',
        'services' => [
            'Web Design',
            'E-commerce App',
            'Data Integration',
            'Database Management',
        ],
    ]);
}
```